# How can I run a certain function on my Service Worker when a specific page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, url, fetch, service-worker

I have an event listener in my service worker for looking at fetch requests:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
    console.log('SERVICE WORKER - FETCH',e.request.url,e);

});
```

Right now it can give me the full url, but I was hoping I could somehow get just the baseURL, not including the domain or any of the parameters. This code will run on different domains, so I can't just separate out that part.

For example, I need to check if the user requested "/logout", but the e.request.url is equal to https://test.mywebsite.com/logout/?redirect=/home.

Is there a good way to do this, or do I have to go the hacky regex route?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like

```
location.href
```

Base URL

```
location.origin
```

Have I misunderstood your question?